# Actualice mi proyecto flutter a android X y me sale este error

Tags: flutter

Actualice mi proyecto flutter a android X y me sale este error, ayuda gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es un proyecto android con modulo de flutter? o es solo flutter? porque usas la libreria sliding panel de android ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Haz un upgrade de tu archivo glade en `android/build.gradle`:

   ```
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
      ...
   }
   ```
2. Si tu proyecto tiene soporte para Kotlin, también tendrás que actualizarlo, quedaría de la siguiente manera `android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        ...
    }
}
```

3. Asegúrate de migrar a AndroidX `gladle.properties` :

```
    org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
    android.enableR8=true
    android.useAndroidX=true
    android.enableJetifier=true
```

Fuente de la [información](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27254)

Comment: excelente funciono, gracias

Comment: Si te funciono, puedes votar la respuesta como "Util", esto dejara saber a otros usuarios que la respuesta le puede ser de utilidad.